# Access App Service from another App Service

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

Hello Access App Service from another App Service

I have an application using Azure App Service Mobile. This service is using Microsoft authentication.

I wanted to create a "Management App" that can extract information, from the first app to display to admins and developers. This is easily possible just by allowing a new app service access to the SQL database. The issue is that I would also like to write pushnotifications to the user with new messages, and more. As to not maintain two notification hubs, I would like to expose a controller that does this.

Therefore my procedure would be:

1. Live App's App Service - Expose Controller APIs - requiring authentication.
2. New app Service for "Management App". Authentication enabled for this app.
3. How do I call a controller created in app service (1) from app service (2), still keeping the users authentications across the call?

How to accomplish (3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only requirement is to allow push notifications, connect the same notification hub to both app services.  This will solve the underlying issue.

You cannot specify two redirect URLs on a single configured client for the Microsoft Account configuration.  Ultimately, this means that you cannot use the same client ID/Secret so that the authentication token can be shared.

An alternative would be to provide an "app shared secret" - this would work because it is not distributed within apps - it is only used between your two backends.

Comment: I thought it was not possible to connect two apps to one notification hub. Because you have to specify the apps sid and secret to get the notification hub to work. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Both mobile app backends need access to the proper connection string (which includes the secrets).  You can connect the same notification hub to both backends.

Comment: Okay, one follow up can I create the link in the portal, or should I copy the connection strings from the old azure portal into the code and deploy the connection strings?

Comment: @JTIM Either way will work. Creating the link is just a shortcut to creating the connection string and will give you an easier way to access the Notification Hub settings.